# Why does after_save not trigger when using touch?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, ruby-on-rails-4

Recent days , I was trying to cache rails app use Redis store.
I have two models:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products

  after_save :clear_redis_cache

  private

    def clear_redis_cache
      puts "heelllooooo"
      $redis.del 'products'
    end
end
```

and

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category, touch: true
end
```

in controller

```
def index
    @products = $redis.get('products')

    if @products.nil?
      @products = Product.joins(:category).pluck("products.id", "products.name", "categories.name")
      $redis.set('products', @products)
      $redis.expire('products', 3.hour.to_i)
    end

    @products = JSON.load(@products) if @products.is_a?(String)

  end
```

With this code , the cache worked fine.
But when I updated or created new product (I have used touch method in relationship) it's not trigger after_save callback in Category model.
Can you explain me why ?

Answer (score 39):

Have you read documentation for [`touch`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/touch) method?

> Saves the record with the updated_at/on attributes set to the current
>   time.  **Please note that no validation is performed and only the
>   after_touch, after_commit and after_rollback callbacks are executed.** 
>   If an attribute name is passed, that attribute is updated along with
>   updated_at/on attributes.

Comment: If all you need is just to trigger **after_save** callbacks please use `save` method.

Answer (score 18):

If you want `after_save` callbacks to be executed when calling `touch` on some model, you can add

```
after_touch :save
```

to this model.

Comment: How does this work? :save is a special word for callbacks?

Comment: it triggers the `save` method after each touch, which will be a no-op, which will in turn trigger the `after_save` callbacks (from what I understood, I'm no expert)

Comment: The problem with this is that the `after_save` method will not actually see any saved changes.

Answer (score 1):

If you set the :touch option to :true, then the updated_at or updated_on timestamp on the associated object will be set to the current time whenever this object is **saved** or **destroyed**
this the doc :
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#touch

Answer (score 0):

You can also (at least in rails 6) just use after_touch: callback

From the docs:

after_touch: Registers a callback to be called after a record is touched. See ActiveRecord::Callbacks for more information.